# Search between date and time in access query

Tags: sql, date, ms-access-2003

I have the following data on a table
tbl Admission : Date and Time are two different fields and stored in `dd/mm/yyyy` format

```
AdmitDate          AdmitTime 
1/6/2012            00:00
3/6/2012            10:00
3/6/2012            19:00
4/6/2012            20:38
5/6/2012            21:00
7/6/2012            03:00
```

I would like to write a query to show all records between 3/6/2012 07:00:00 and 5/6/2012 06:59:59.

The query should also have the option of having 'date' input from user (only the date & time can be the fixed interval between 7 am first day to 6 59 am the second day) - for instance using PARAMETERS.
I use access 2003.
I tried several queries but am not able to perfect one - i do not get accurate results.
Somebody please help.

Thanks,

Regards,

Comment: What is the datatype of `AdmitDate` ?

Comment: AdmitDate : dateTime and AdmitTime : dateTime too

Comment: Then why do you need `AdmitTime` as well? Why not store both values in the same column?

Comment: I understand , but i am not in a position to change field data types now. This access table is more over linked to sql server. But i just need help with finding an access query to create an access report.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there was only one `DATETIME` column, the condition for the query would be easy to be constructed:

```
WHERE AdmitDateTime >= '2012-06-03 07:00' 
  AND AdmitDateTime <  '2012-06-05 07:00'
```

---

Since you can't do that and because Access has its own Date and Time functions, I think this will work:

```
WHERE DateValue(AdmitDate) + AdmitTime 
         >= DateValue([InputDate]) + TimeValue('07:00')
  AND DateValue(AdmitDate) + AdmitTime 
         <  DateValue([InputDate]) + 2 + TimeValue('07:00')
```

The `DateValue()` calls are there to ensure that any time parts in the values passed by the user or in the `AdmitDate` column are chopped off and only the `'07:00'` and the `AdmitTime` are used.

Comment: I tried this : SELECT * From ADmission
Where (((AdmitDate + AdmitTime) >= #1/6/2012 10:00#) AND ((AdmitDate + AdmitTime) <=  #3/6/2012 15:00#) ) but get weird results.

Comment: Works Like a charm !!! I modified it to PARAMETERS Start_Date DateTime,End_Date DateTime;
SELECT AdmitDate, AdmitTime
FROM Admit_PtLocations
WHERE DateValue(AdmitDate) + AdmitTime 
         >= DateValue(Start_Date) + TimeValue('07:00')
  AND DateValue(AdmitDate) + AdmitTime 
         <  DateValue(End_Date) + TimeValue('07:00')
ORDER BY AdmitDate,AdmitTime ASC   ... Thanks Again ...

Comment: Building on newly acquired knowledge?

Comment: @Remou: is that comment for me or for Mohammed? Not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

All office dates are numbers, so you can add:

```
SELECT [admitdate]+[admittime] AS Expr1
FROM dt
WHERE ((([admitdate]+[admittime]) 
  Between #6/3/2012 7:0:0# And #6/5/2012 6:59:59#));
```

The above will work in the query design window but anywhere else, such as VBA you will run into locale problems.

Edit re comment

```
Result
03/06/2012 10:00:00
03/06/2012 19:00:00
04/06/2012 20:38:00
```

Comment: Im having a problem : the above query works but gives me results from 5th to 7th ..... weird !!!!! any ideas why that is happening ? i tried changing dates and its always 2 days forwards ......

Comment: MS Access uses US dates for the most part. In order to ensure that there is no ambiguity, it is usually best to enter dates in yyyy/mm/dd format. What did you type in?

Comment: I put in dd/mm/yy .... though i did try yyyy/mm/dd ... but i get the same results (2 days forwards).

Comment: Thanks again for the help. You can find the answer above.